# How to make bootstrap render grid system as a viewport size other than is actualy be showing?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

My application shows a "layout preview" that uses Bootstrap grid system.

I Would like the user to switch between mobile, tablet and desktop preview on the page and be able to see the different layouts.

I rather to do not use iframes.

How can I change the bootstrap render grid system as `sm`, `md`, `lg` but not bounded to the real viewport size?

Comment: Well, you can try to remove the classes for higher breakpoints when selecting to preview the smaller viewports, since Bootstrap classes apply to the specified breakpoint forward, if you remove the class `col-lg-*`, the block will receive the style of `col-md-*` and so on

Comment: It is bound to viewport size since Bootstrap uses media queries.